# What is the correct command line to tell install-tl to use the mirror I tell it?

Tags: texlive, ctan

I'm updating TeX on my systems, and have been having issues with very slow install speeds (Estimated finishing times of over 19 hours at times for a 1.9 GB install). I think this might be since testing indicates that CTAN selects mirrors based on what country I'm in, and the nearest Canadian mirror is 1800 km away in Winnipeg (The others are further, one being on the opposite coast).

I would like to manually tell it to use the [Seattle mirror](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/), since that is a *lot* closer to me (Under 200 km), and thus probably faster.*

I've been trying the command line: `tlpkg\tlperl\bin\perl.exe install-tl -gui perltk -repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/` which returns an error that it can't find the texlive.tlpdb file.

So what have I entered wrong? Is this the wrong URL? I also tried `tlpkg\tlperl\bin\perl.exe install-tl -gui perltk -repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/` with the same error.

(I also tried `-select-repository`, but that fails with an error, possibly related to the fact I'm running the perl file directly, since batch files are blocked on this PC by the security software, but I figure that will be harder to fix.)

*(Based 3 trials with each server, Seattle, then Manitoba, then Seattle, and so on, Seattle was 1.6 MB/s, vs ~500 KB/s from Winnipeg. One time Winnipeg got up to 1.1 MB/s, but both other trials it was between 300-600 KB/s).

Comment: Note that the tlmgr repo url always ends with `tlnet`, so yes your urls are wrong.

Comment: Besides distance, server load and connection are factors. For me it took 20 min for a full TeX Live installation via http://ctan.net. (see https://tex.blogoverflow.com/2018/08/ctan-mirror/) I ran `install-tl -repository http://ctan.net/systems/texlive/tlnet`. It's in Germany, so higher distance means higher latency but the bandwidth could be good, but only bigger files may benefit.

Comment: I have been having problems with MikTeX packages lately, but it times out rather than wait until the server is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the wrong directory, you need to use `http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/`. Furthermore, I suggest using `install-tl-advanced.bat -repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet` since it also properly sets up the PERL5LIB env variable etc.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but the whole reason I was using the command line in the first place was that bat files won't run on that system due to security permissions. While I'm in charge of managing that computer, and specifically allowed to install software on it, I'd have to bother the department tech support to come and disable that permission to use the bat file. Which I probably should do, as they are quite useful.